# Data autorize attribute not working inside javascript append

Tags: javascript, jquery

if anyone can help me please I am stuck with this, I need to autoresize the height of textarea and it is working well, in the blade part of laravel

```
<textarea  data-autoresize rows="1" type="text"  class="form-control inline-block textfield"></textarea>
```

and the javascript part

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.each(jQuery('textarea[data-autoresize]'), function() {
        var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight;
        var resizeTextarea = function(el) {
            jQuery(el).css('height', 'auto').css('height', el.scrollHeight + offset);
        };
        jQuery(this).on('keyup input', function() { resizeTextarea(this); }).removeAttr('data-autoresize');
    });
    </script>
```

But I also have this javascript part

```
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add_field').click(function () {
    i++;
    $('.optionsForm').append('<div id="textfield' + i + '" class="col-md-6 min-height-60 textfield"><textarea data-autoresize rows="1" type="text" id="textfield" name="question_text' + i + '" value="{{ old('options') }}" class="form-control inline-block textfield" placeholder="@lang('general.textfield') ' + i + '"></textarea>@if($errors->has('options. + i + '))<span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('options. + i + ') }}</strong></span>@endif<button type="button" value="' + i + '" class="btn btn-flat btn-default btn-sm inline-block d-button d-textfield" id="delete_textfield" title="@lang('general.remove_option')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>');
        });
```

And here the data-autoresize  is not working I think,  because it is not autoresizing, can anyone please help, thank you.

Comment: try replacing "keyup input" with just "keyup" in ur code  
 ====> jQuery(this).on('keyup input'

Comment: thanks but it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

jQuery event handlers are attached to DOM elements that exist at the time the DOM is loaded.  You are adding new `textarea`s after the DOM has loaded, so your event handlers aren't attached to them, and they don't run.

You need to delegate your handler to something that exists at the time of page load.  The [jQuery docs describe this](http://api.jquery.com/on/), see the "Direct and delegated events" section.

You also need to restructure your code a bit, I think.  I am not sure why you need to iterate over each textarea, instead of just assigning one keyup event?  Try the following:

**UPDATED** there were a few typos.

```
// Attach an event handler on body, which will exist at load, and filter it
// (you could use any other element that all your textareas will be inside, that
// exists at the time the page loads)
jQuery('body').on('keyup input', 'textarea[data-autoresize]', function(e) { 
    resizeTextarea(jQuery(e.target));
});

// Single function to handle keyup resizes.
function resizeTextarea($textarea) {
    var offset = $textarea.offsetHeight - $textarea.clientHeight;
    $textarea.css('height', 'auto').css('height', el.scrollHeight + offset).removeAttr('data-autoresize');
};
```